# Remove the history of a Drive in the registry windows 10

Tags: windows-10, registry, regedit

I'm familiar with windows systems, I work as a network admin with 7 enterprise, but this stumped me with one of my personal pc's.

I have a computer that is running windows 10 with 2 drive now, previously had a third one until it failed. I removed the D: drive and started downloading my games on my other one G: drive. I can not remove old installations of previously installed games on through app and features nor can I install games.

Example is fortnite, it says that it can not find D:...\fortnite...... Which makes sense since the drive is not in the computer. I have gone through the registry and removed (what I can see) all keys associated with the D: drive.

Is there a program or way to just remove all keys automatically associated with the missing drive? I tried CCleaner, Disk Cleanup, and one more my coworker recommended that I don't recall the name of. I ran Avast system check to see if it would notice the missing drive.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Run disc clean up.

Comment: I did and it still won't let me install what was installed on the previous drive, I tried using the registry repair with CCleaner as well.

Comment: Something else for your arsenal

Comment: CLeaner is good, but you disk cleanup, then defrag, then open cmd and I think you have to run it as administrator, run sfc scannow and when that finishes run the chkdisk

Answer (score 0):

Found an accidental solution, my little brother installed windows on the wrong computer so I guess this works.